# URL RegExp WITHOUT http:// or www

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm trying to construct URL RegExp. The base expression looks like:

```
/^(((http(?:s)?\:\/\/)|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?:\/?|(?:\/[\w\-]+)*)(?:\/?|\/\w+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})?)(?:\?[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:\&[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)*)$/
```

It looks good for me, because matches these:

```
http://gmail.com
http://www.gmail.com
www.gmail.com
```

But I wold like to modify it to match this:

```
gmail.com
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: If you build such a regex, this will match `too.right`? While it isn't an URL... You really should keep the `http://` prefix.

Comment: @sp00m yes, you are correct! but the "too.right" looks more user friendly for user than "http://too.right". I think nowadays it's quite common to see such a notation.

Comment: @Roberto Sánchez yes, it's JavaScript!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add a `?` to make `www` optional, then it will match gmail.com also

use this :

```
^(((http(?:s)?\:\/\/)|www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?:\/?|(?:\/[\w\-]+)*)(?:\/?|\/\w+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})?)(?:\?[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:\&[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)*)$
```

or if you want to match **only** `gmail.com` and **not** `http://gmail.com` in that case use this :

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?:\/?|(?:\/[\w\-]+)*)(?:\/?|\/\w+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})?)(?:\?[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:\&[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)*)$
```

please note , this will match anu string which has dots and alphabets in it.

IMO it will be better off using a regex like this :

```
^(http:\/\/|www\.)?[\w\.]+\.(com|net|co\.cc|co\.in)$
```

you can modify it according to your needs .

check out a demo here and play around with the regex :

http://regex101.com/r/tS4aB3

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I just added a '?' and it seems to be working well, expect one case: 
www.gmail is treated as valid email. Is it possible to treat it as invalid? It's not so important but anyway.

Comment: only if you have a list of url extensions, then only we can blacklist them as i have done in my final example

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to treat 'www' as just another subdomain (because that's all it is).

So:

```
/^(((http(?:s)?\:\/\/))?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.?)+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?:\/?|(?:\/[\w\-]+)*)(?:\/?|\/\w+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})?)(?:\?[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:\&[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)*)$/
```

**Edit:** as a side note, the tld (i.e. the ".com" part) is... quite complicated these days. There are a lot of them, and they may not fit easily in 2-6 chars.

Comment: Thank you, it's working! Just a question, how can I exclude www.gmail from a list of valid urls?